# how to send variable from gridview yii to javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, gridview, yii

i need your help. my purpose is update data in modal form, but i get problem and almost one week i didn't find the solution. the problem is i don't know how to send  id from gridview to javascript function and in javascript function will throught to controller but in controller I can't get the variable of id. this my code.

```
//code  in admin.php
 'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
              'template'=>'{view} {update} {delete} ',
                'buttons'=>array(           

                 'update' => array
                (
    'click'=>'js:function()
                    {
                    var idcab=($(this).parent().parent().children(":nth-child(1)").text());
                    editCabang(idcab);
                    $("#dialogClassroom").dialog("open");
                    }', 

                ),


$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array( // the dialog
    'id'=>'dialogClassroom',
    'options'=>array(
        'title'=>'Tambah Cabang',
        'autoOpen'=>false,
     // set to auto open for testing only
                            'draggable'=>true,
                            'resizable'=>true,
                            'closeOnEscape' => true,                                                       
                           // 'show'=>'fade',
                           // 'hide'=>'fade',
                             'position'=>array(300,50),
                            'modal'=>true,
                            'width'=>'700px',
                            'height'=>'auto',
        'close' => 'js:function(event, ui) { location.href = "./admin" }'
    ),
));?>
<div class="divForForm"></div>

<?php $this->endWidget();?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function editCabang(idcab)
{
 //alert(idcab); when i alert the id show 

    <?php echo CHtml::ajax(array(
           'url'=>array('Tbcabang/update'), 
           'data'=> 'js:$(this).serialize(),"idcab2":$(this).idcab', //i want send variable idcab2 to controller

            'type'=>'post',
            'dataType'=>'json',
            'success'=>"function(data)
            {
                if (data.status == 'failure')
                {
                    $('#dialogClassroom div.divForForm').html(data.div);
                          // Here is the trick: on submit-> once again this function!
                    $('#dialogClassroom div.divForForm form').submit(editCabang);
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#dialogClassroom div.divForForm').html(data.div);
                    setTimeout(\"$('#dialogClassroom').dialog('close') \",3000);
                }

            } ",
            ))
            ?>;
    return false; 

}

//code in controller (update action)
public function actionUpdate()
    {
        //$id=100;
        $id=$_POST[idcab2]; //the id is empty

        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        if(isset($_POST['Tbcabang']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Tbcabang'];
            if($model->save())
            {
             if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
                {
                    echo CJSON::encode(array(
                        'status'=>'success', 
                        'div'=>"Tambah cabang berhasil"
                        ));

                    exit;               
                }
                else
                //    $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id_cabang));

            }
        }


        if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
        {
            echo CJSON::encode(array(
                'status'=>'failure', 
                'div'=>$this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model), true,true)));
            exit;               
        }
     else
            $this->render('update',array('model'=>$model,));
}
```

Comment: where are you passing id to js function?

Comment: did you try  `editCabang("$data->id");` in update array?

Comment: i'm passing from gridview when user the click update buttton it will send variable to function editCabang(idcab), variable idcab has succes send to that function, but in that function i also send variable to controller Tbcabang/update which i can't receive variable idcab in my controller

Comment: what do you receive in $_POST array ?

Answer (score 0):

The expression `js:$(this).serialize(),"idcab2":$(this).idcab` doesn't make any sense..

How is `$(this)` going to work, and it should be just a javascript object..

To pass the `idcab` variable passed to the function to the controller you need to use just the `idcab` not `$(this).idcab`

Comment: i have try "idcab2":idcab to send variable to controller but in controller i can't receive the idcab2 variable which i'm using $_POST['idcab2'] to get it

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you can fix it . But what I get you want to show dialog for editing a grid so the best way is to to pass id to that dialog e. g

```
 //code  in admin.php
 'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
              'template'=>'{view} {update} {delete} ',
                'buttons'=>array(           

                 'update' => array
                (
 'click'=>'js:function()
 {
   var idcab=($(this).parent().parent().children(":nth-child(1)").text());
   //set the id 
   $("#dialogClassroom").dialog("option","idcab",idcab);
   $("#dialogClassroom").dialog("open");
 }',
```

),

Then add open event to dialog to fetch the data/or set the form   :

```
'close' => 'js:function(event, ui) { location.href = "./admin" }'
  'open' => 'js:function(event, ui) {
      var idcab=$(ui).dialog("option","idcab");
      //fetch the data for idcab and fill the dialog form , is that you want ?
      //if yes call the ajax function now  
   }'
```

Probably you can set the open event function of dialog to set a hidden form field. You know what you are doing .

Comment: thanks for your code. but i need var idcab send to controller , if u see in my code i send the idcab through the function editcabang, how i can send var idcab to controller ?

Comment: I explained it above already . When you open the dialog,say it has `<form><input name='id'>...` you will update the form id with idcap. Or fetch the data through ajax . Please explain flow of operation and what `editCabang` function is actually doing.

Comment: editCabang function for send variable to Tbcabang/update controller. thanks

Comment: you just need to change the line :  `'data'=> 'js:$(this).serialize(),"idcab2":idcab'`, with `this` removed . Let me know how this works